# Connecting to database suddenly started throwing exception for my website

Tags: sql-server

I have an MVC3 application hosted by third party hosting provider. The site has been running well for the past 3 months without any problems. Today suddenly the Application started throwing following Exception as recorded in my logs part of which is shown below.

> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return
>   a ProviderManifestToken string. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout
>   period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is
>   not responding.

The message is self explanatory and I first thought I should increase the connect timeout, but then the exception was still thrown suggesting the other part (Server Not Responding). I contacted my hosting provider and he said there was nothing wrong on his part. So I am stuck with a down website and don't know what to do.

Any ideas why the provider is throwing the exception listed above. Also, is it possible for me to remotely connect to the database on the hosting server with limited authority. Any tools for that ? I don't have an exposure in database subject, except for application programming.

Comment: check your server may be disconnected. Try after some time, by seeing the server is connected.

Comment: No idea for the error; but as a database management tool, you can use [database.net](http://fishcodelib.com/Database.htm) or MSSQL Management Studio Express edition.

Comment: @Sai Even I think that server is disconnected. So I spoke again and the site admin is looking into it now. Will keep this thread updated accordingly.@denolk, I have the Management Studio Express edition. Will study about how to connect to remote server. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @Nirvan, did you refer to the link I provided in the answer?

Comment: @Sai No actually I didn't. Can you repost the same. Sorry for that but I was a little overconfident that the timeout won't happen.

Comment: Can you please post a copy of the Inner Exception?

Answer (score 0):

This occurs due to the Timeout, the default timeout is 30 seconds, for time out there are 2 common reasons.

Long running tasks or uncommitted transactions. Refer to the [Timeout expired](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/07/31/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation-or-the-server-is-not-responding.aspx) to know about this.

Comment: No its not a problem with timeout. I have increased timeout in my web.config and I don't have any long running queries either.